# Power Apps, Save as a PDF

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, pdf, printing, powerapps-canvas

Can't seem to find a button where I can export a power app page as a pdf/csv.

Is there any simple way of adding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft released printing feature in Power Apps couple of months ago.

**Announcement**: [Print() screens in your canvas app](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/print-screens-in-your-canvas-app/)

---

You can use **Print()** function to send any Power apps screen to a printer for printing or to save it as a PDF file.

**Basic steps**:

1. Open your app in Power apps studio
2. Select **Insert** from the menu and then select **Button**.
3. From the property list on the top left, select **OnSelect**.
4. Enter the formula `Print()`.
5. Save, publish & play the app.

When you select the button, a default print browser pops up and allows you to choose from the available options to print or save it as a PDF file:

[image]

---

OR you can start with new screen template named **Portrait print** in your app.

[image]

**Documentation**: [Print function in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-print)

Comment: Thanks, this kind of works, it seems like it only takes what it seen and not the full page. Ie I may have a scroll on my power app page, and it will miss the data below. Is there anyway to capture the full page?

Comment: Check this [YouTube video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=95BS378sJ1k). It should help you.